# What does after the wisest mean in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, archaic-language, literature

This is a quote from "The Tempest" by Stephano:

> He's in his fit now and does not talk after the
>   wisest.

What does "after the wisest" mean in this context? According to most of the sources of translation, the sentence means

> He’s having a fit, and saying things that don't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use of **after** is [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/after)'s definition 3c :

> "in the characteristic manner of" or "in imitation of"

So the meaning of your quote would be

"He's in the middle of a fit (some kind of seizure or mental health crisis) now and does not talk in the wisest manner."

Sort of a polite understatement for, "He's talking crazy."

Answer (score 0):

*After* here means *according to*, or *following the manner of*.